# kafka consumer offset stops increasing frequently

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer, the offset will move correctly for a while, but after some random time, the offset will stop, to solve this, I need to change a consumer group id, and back and force.

Not sure how to solve this problem. I checked zookeeper, the offset value was there, just didn't change at all.

Comment: I cannot follow completely... Can you describe your problem more precise? Did you check the log files for errors ?

Comment: I checked the logs, there was no errors at all. The question is that my kafka consumer can't read message from kafka after I started the consumer for some time, unless I change the consumer's group id.

Comment: Is your producer constantly writing data into the topic? What is your setting for parameter "auto.offset.reset"?

Comment: Yes, the producer constantly writing data into the topic, the lag was the reason to find the problem. I didn't configure auto.offset.reset, it should be the default value which is largest. Can this problem caused by zookeeper?

Comment: Which Kafka version do you use?

Comment: 2.11-0.8.2.1, is there any known issue on this version? or do I need to upgrade

Comment: Don't know. Upgrading might be a good idea thought. There is already 0.10 release with many major improvements...